# View PDF as "node"/content

Tags: 7, files

I'm working on updating our current intranet to Drupal.

What I need to be able to do is take a PDF and load it in an iframe/node via Adobe Reader (or similar).

I can get something similar using (I think) CCK and FileViewer, but I'd like to remove the fileviewer wrapper and just have a standard PDF in browser.

Assume IE7/8 and Adobe Reader are installed.

**Update:**
Custom Formatter Module: [Custom Module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5108.jpg)
Result of Module: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNbM3.jpg)

***Update 2***
[image]
Using an Object per [these instructions](http://pdfobject.com/markup/index.php) gives a more controlled block to build on. Ultimately I'll add a "You need Adobe installed from HERE to view THIS PDF" for the small chance of no pdf-viewer installed.

Comment: what drupal version are you targetting? cck suggests d6 but its not entirely clear! :)

Comment: The more I think about this the more I realize that if you want to open the file via Adobe Reader inside the browser than its not really a Drupal issue at all.

Comment: added D7 tag. It's a drupal issue if I'm presenting the pdf via my drupal website. the content (pdf) isn't drupal, but the presentation medium is. I will try "generic file" later today as I have time :) I hope that's all that is needed, because that would rock and solve a big question for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using an `<iframe>` element within a custom formatter for a *file* field.

Field formatters control the output of a field: it's what lets you choose whether to display a generic link, the file name, etc. What you can do is create one that displays the PDF within an `<iframe>` element.

To do this, you need to (at a minimum) implement two hooks: [`hook_field_formatter_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_info/7) and [`hook_field_formatter_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_view/7):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_info().
 */
function sandbox_field_formatter_info() {
  $info = array();
  $info['sandbox_formatter'] = array(
    'label' => t('Inline file'),
    'description' => t('Display the file within an iframe.'),
    'field types' => array('file'),
  );
  return $info;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_view().
 */
function sandbox_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
  $element = array();

  // Create the proper markup for each item within the field instance
  foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
    $path = file_create_url($item['uri']);
    $element[$delta] = array(
      '#markup' => '<iframe src="' . $path . '"></iframe>',
    );
  }
  return $element;
}
```

Then you can create a file field, set it to only allow PDF, and choose *Inline file* as the display format. When you view a node with a PDF, you'll see the PDF within an `<iframe>` element.

The above is a very basic, minimal example: for an intermediate example that shows how to implement formatter settings, check out [Dan Linn's tutorial](http://www.metaltoad.com/node/416). Also be sure to check out the relevant API pages, which includes sample implementations even more advanced than Linn's:

- [File Types API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/group/field_types/7)
- [`hook_field_formatter_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_info/7)
- [`hook_field_formatter_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_view/7)
- [`hook_field_formatter_settings_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field_ui--field_ui.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_settings_form/7)
- [`hook_field_formatter_settings_summary()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field_ui--field_ui.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_settings_summary/7)

As an aside, it should be noted that there are a couple of related modules:

- [Iframe](http://drupal.org/project/iframe): creates an `<iframe>` element formatter, but it hasn't been ported to Drupal 7 yet.
- [Custom formatters](http://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters): claims to allow the creation of custom formatters without needing to create a custom module

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the PDF in browser window and Adobe Reader + plugins are installed then just use CCK to implement a FileField and display it as "Generic File". The browser will handle opening it automatically. No Drupal magic or skills required...

Comment: I have a content, setup as simply a title and a "generic file". The problem is it is simply showing a link to the file - click to open/save. I want the file loaded in the browser. Our current intranet makes heavy use of top menu, side menu and content loaded in the "body", of which a PDF is used most often. I'll post some pictures and do a little more research later today.